# Azure Search Explain function

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to understand how the scoring has been generated for Azure Search matches as some of my results are distinctly odd (though probably correct if only I understood why!). There is nothing officially documented but is there anything like Lucene Explain for Azure Search?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The default scoring method use the TF-IDF algorithm to calculate a value for each searchable field in the document. Those values are then summed up together to create a final score.

More details on TFIDF here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

You can alter the score further by using scoring profiles to boost the score of certain fields. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index

Comment: Thanks ramero but that doesn't really help. I understand scoring profiles and vaguely understand TF-IDF but I'm getting relevancy scores that I don't understand why.... and my customers are asking why too as it looks like a bug to them. It would be helpful if I could ask Azure Search why it's rated something the way it has, similar to Lucene

Comment: Unfortunately, as of today, we do not expose an "explain" API. You can vote for the following suggestion to help us prioritize the work in the future:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7379515-support-explain-api

In the mean time, if you give us more details on your scenario and the results you are getting, we can try to help you further understand the score. If you don't feel comfortable sharing that information on stack overflow, feel free to send us an email directly at azscustquestions at microsoft dot com

Comment: Thanks ramero - I'll see what I can pull out but really I need the ability to check myself as it could be one of many oddities. As for User Voice... nothing against you but don't get me started, that's a place where ideas tend to go to die as they are on there for years with high votes and nothing ever gets done about them. This particular issue is < 100 votes whereas others are 1000+ and still not dealt with, so I'm not hopeful

Comment: @GrahamB, you're right. We've been slow addressing feedback regarding user-facing features as our focus has been mostly on improving reliability, performance, security, regional roll-out etc. We're working hard to address most pressing customer asks, like Complex Types and others from the top of UserVoice. Unfortunately, the Explain API is not on the roadmap for the next 6 months. Please reach out if we can help with anything in the meantime by improving documentation, samples etc. Users find this article useful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture

Answer (score 0):

He there, I was having the same problem that you're having. A client of mine was asking me to help improve on search performance. I therefore reverse engineered the Azure Search scoring algorithm and documented it in a blog. Please take a look at it and let me know if its helpful.

It basically comes down to the following equation.

`totalscore = (weightedfieldscores) ∗ (functionaggregration)`

`weighted field scores = (f*w) + (f*w) + ...`
Where is `f` the TF-IDF score of the field, and `w` the weight configured in the scoring profile for the corresponding field. The summation of the weighted field scores is the total weighted field score.

This will be multiplied by the aggregated function score. Which is the following:
`functionaggregration = fa(f1(x), f2(x), ...)`.
Where `fa` is the aggregation functions, this can be the sum of all functions or the firs, or average, etc. And `f1`, `f2` are the tag, magnitude, etc. functions themselves.

Please let me know if this is helpful.

https://dibranmulder.github.io/2020/09/22/Improving-your-Azure-Seach-performance/